# JavaScript "ReferenceError: value is not defined" error when using Console.log

Tags: javascript

I am using a modified version of a JavaScript Slider bar from a [tutorial by Thoriq Firdaus](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/jquery-volumn-slider/)

I am trying to print the variable `value` to my Firefox console using `console.log(value)` but I keep getting the below error

> ReferenceError: value is not defined
>
> console.log(value)

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong?

```
$(function () {
    var initX=0,minX=50,width=400;        
    var slider = $('#slider'),
        tooltip = $('.tooltip');

    slider.slider({
        //Config
        min: -50,
        max: +50,
        value: 0,

        start: function (event, ui) {
            tooltip.fadeIn('fast');
        },

        //Slider Event
        slide: function (event, ui) { 
            var value = slider.slider('value'),
                volume = $('.volume');

            tooltip.css('left', initX+(value*width)/100).text(ui.value); 
        },

        stop: function (event, ui) {
        },
    });
    initX=slider.slider("value");

    console.log(value)

    var txt=initX;
   initX+=(minX*width)/100;
tooltip.css('left',initX).text(txt);
});
```

Comment: value doesn't exist in that scope (outside of `slider.slider`)

Comment: You don't have such a variable there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by @snemy and @SLaks, the variable 'value' is only visible in the scope of the function call containing its declaration.

So, to clarify, this will work :

```
    //Slider Event
    slide: function (event, ui) { 
        var value = slider.slider('value'),
            volume = $('.volume');

        console.log(value);

        tooltip.css('left', initX+(value*width)/100).text(ui.value); 
    }
```

But not what you've tried, since the variable value is not visible where you've put your `console.log` statement ; and the `slide` function has probably not been called yet.

You can read more about scopes [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Function_scope), in case you're new to the language.

Comment: Thank you, and for the reference, yes I'm completely new to JS.

Comment: @Deepend then I highly recommend you spend some time on MDN to grasp the language before copy-pasting too much jquery code. Have fun !